# Wicked PDF not making AJAX / JS calls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, wicked-pdf

I am currently using JS and Ajax requests to edit some HTML tags depending on certain controller method results. This is all working fine until I want to Generate a PDF, I have been doing some research and have found some "solutions" to this using the **javascript_delay** and **window-status** but was unsuccessful.

Following the guide of **wkhtmltopdf** I am using the **wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag** to load the JS file and this is being written and saved, but I dont know if the Javascript is being executed as the "visual" part is generated in the AJAX part of the .js file which is not being shown in the PDF.

The controller is returning a complete HTML that I want to visualise in a HTML container:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/monitor/device/"+widget.property.device_sensor,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html'
}).done(function (datos) {
  $container.html(datos);
}).always(function () {
  redBorder.widgets.util.reloadDone($container.parents('.widget'));
});
```

This is using the GEM **wkhtmltopdf** in Rails

**How can I know that the JS is being executed and if it is being executed and the issue is with the AJAX call how could this be fixed?**

Answer (score 1):

During rendering with `wicked-pdf` the page is saved to a temporary file on disk and opened via `file://` protocol. The result is that page knows nothing about your server address, and even if it did - it will have different origin, which by default prevents ajax calls (need to setup CORS to bypass that).

For pdfs it's better to get rid of ajax calls, because obviously there'll be no user interaction, and render all necessary data in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var httpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }
    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
    httpRequest.responseType = 'text';
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        /do stuff
      }
    };
    httpRequest.send();
```

This replaces the ajax call with pure javascript. Hope this was of help, Pedro.

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank, I've already attempted this but was unsuccessful as there is still some communication error going on between the controller and the XMLHttpRequest. This was apparently solved using a cookie but we are not receiving the information returned by the controller.

See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895869/xmlhttprequest-returning-empty-responsetext-and-readystate-4-wickedpf